# Pending transactions at the client machine, but minter is not minting a new block since there are no pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, quorum, raft

I am running Blockbench on Quorom Raft using smallbank workload: 4 minters and 4 clients. Following the logs, I found that sometimes 1 specific client (Client 4) has pending transactions but the minter stop minting as there is no transactions to mint. Do you have any idea what the issue could be.

**Quorom start mining:**

```
PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup ${QUORUM} --datadir $QUO_DATA --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8000 --port 9000 --raft --raftport 50400 --raftblocktime 70 --mine --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --unlock 0 --password <(echo -n "") > $QUO_DATA/../raft_quorum_log 2>&1 &
```

**Genesis:**

```
  "alloc": {
     "eb6902c98ed64b7b16f743a7c09b36b8fa1aff59": {
      "balance":"1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "981010def42136f95ad6f302052e660bac5f2b3f": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
   "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "config": {
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock":0,
    "chainId": 10,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "isQuorum": true
  },
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x1FFFFFFFE0",
  "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

**Starting Client:**

```
nohup ./driver -db ethereum -ops 10000 -threads $1 -txrate  $4 -st $5 -fp stat.txt -endpoint $ip:8000 > $LOG_DIR/host_$ip"_"$1"_"$6 2>&1 &
```

threads: 4
txrate: 500
st: ~ 600 seconds

Note that I always found this in the log files either there was pending transactions or not:
`VM returned with error                   err="gas uint64 overflow"`

Comment: I would try to change `"gasLimit": "0x1FFFFFFFE0"` (though it doesn't seem like something that should cause an overflow) to something like 8000000.

Comment: Can you share the contract? Likely you have an int overflow in that.